# HTML/JS: Replace special characters (mostly apostrophes and commas) so that it doesn't screw up a SQL Statement

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I have created a survey (form) that collects data from users and inserts them into an Access database (for internal purposes). The problem is that, in the text fields, if someone puts and apostrophe (say their last name is O'Connor) it terminates my SQL Statement. How can I change that so it doesn't happen anymore?

```
   var nameCheck = document.getElementById("name").value;
var zipCheck = document.getElementById("zip").value;
var phoneCheck = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var addressCheck = document.getElementById("address").value;
var emailCheck = document.getElementById("email").value;
var contactCheck = document.getElementById("contacttime").value;
```

.
.
.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Database (name, address, zip, phone, email, contact) VALUES('"+ nameCheck +"','"+ addressCheck +"','"+ zipCheck +"','"+ phoneCheck +"','"+ emailCheck +"','"+ contactCheck +"')"
```

Also the server we have is from 1998 and apparently it cannot understand PHP.

Comment: You're building SQL queries with JavaScript? Now I've seen it all.

Comment: Escaping special characters is one of the benefits of using query parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Don't EVER rely on the client to construct your query, nor rely on escaping characters to make your query valid. You're opening a can of worms, security-wise (read about SQL injection). Use query parameters on the server side, as suggested by Dan in the comments.